# Python- Error while deploying Django app on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I followed the steps on [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration) I configured all well maybe miss something. Pushed codes to the git. But when I run command `git push --set-upstream heroku master`, I get this following error.

**ERROR**

```
remote:        ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_heroku'
remote:
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
remote:
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
remote:
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
remote:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
```

I pip installed django_heroku module and wrote this code

```
import django_heroku
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

at the very bottom in settings.py so what's the problem here?

Comment: The error is clearly telling you that django_heroku is not found. Did you install it? Show your requirements.txt or Pipfile.

Comment: You should add `django-heroku` to your `requirements.txt` file and `django-heroku = "*"` to `Pipfile` file too

Comment: Thanks guys. I was not updated my requirements.txt file

Comment: please read this documentation , it is very helpfull https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/09/how-to-deploy-django-applications-on-heroku.html